# Quick object modification with dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I'm pretty new to programming, and I'm trying to find the most efficient way to iterate an object to update it's state with each pass. I thought I could use the dictionary in Python 3.6 to run the code in the object. I was hoping to see output that reads:

```
Tank A is clean    
dirty    
Tank B is dirty    
clean
```

and end up with the tank objects mode switched. Why doesn't this work, and what's the most efficient way to choose the correct def from the instantiated tank to run?

```
class Tank:
    def __init__(self, mode, name):
        self.mode = mode
        self.name = name
    def dirty(self):
        print("%s is dirty"%(self.name))
        self.mode = 'clean'
        return self
    def clean(self):
        print("%s is clean"%(self.name))
        self.mode = 'dirty'
        return self
i = 0
tankList = []
tankList.append(Tank('clean', "Tank A"))
tankList.append(Tank('dirty', "Tank B"))

while i < 2:
    #create the mode lookup
    dict = {'clean': tankList[i].clean(), 'dirty': tankList[i].dirty()}
    #update the tank mode
    tankList[i] = dict[tankList[i].mode]
    #display the tank mode
    print(tankList[i].mode)
    i += 1
```

Comment: you show what you want the code to print/do, but not what it currently does. That might help answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a class. You can always just hold all your tanks in a dict and update/display the state of your tanks by accessing those properties.

```
tanks = {}

tanks['tankA'] = {'name': 'Tank A', 'mode': 'clean'}
tanks['tankB'] = {'name': 'Tank B', 'mode': 'dirty'}

for t in tanks:
    print('{} is {}'.format(tanks[t]['name'], tanks[t]['mode']))

print('updating Tank A mode...')

tanks['tankA']['mode'] = 'dirty'

for t in tanks:
    print('{} is {}'.format(tanks[t]['name'], tanks[t]['mode']))
```

The result would look like this:

```
Tank A is clean
Tank B is dirty
updating Tank A mode...
Tank A is dirty
Tank B is dirty
```

The dict looks like this:

```
{'tankA': {'name': 'Tank A', 'mode': 'dirty'}, 'tankB': {'name': 'Tank B', 'mode': 'dirty'}}
```

You could then create methods to update your dict in certain ways based on your own logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I never thought about wether I needed a class or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By redefining the `dict` in every loop, you are calling the class methods each time, so all `Tank` instances end up with the same `mode`. You can avoid this with a simple `if...else...` condition instead of a `dict`.
This will work as your `while` loop:

```
while i < 2:
    if tankList[i].mode == 'dirty':
        tankList[i].dirty()
    elif tankList[i].mode == 'clean':
        tankList[i].clean()
    print(tankList[i].mode)
    i += 1
```

Output as required:

```
Tank A is clean
dirty
Tank B is dirty
clean
```